# set literals weren't supported until version 2.2 flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

also it says this error : set literals weren't supported until version 2.2 flutter

this is my import on signup.dart

```
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../db/users.dart';
```

this is my variable code:

```
 class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
        }

        class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
          final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
          final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
          UserServices _userServices = UserServices();
          TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
          TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
          TextEditingController _nameTextController = TextEditingController();
          TextEditingController _confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
          String gender;
          String groupValue = "male";
          bool hidePass = true;
          bool loading = false;
```

i think the problem is in this code below:

```
      void validateForm() async {
        FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
        Map value;
        if (formState.validate()) {
          FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
          if (user == null) {
            firebaseAuth
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: _emailTextController.text,
                    password: _passwordTextController.text)
                .then((user) => {

                  _userServices.createUser(
                  user.uid,
                      {
                        "username": user.displayName,
                        "email": user.email,
                        "userId": user.uid,
                        "gender": gender,
                      }
                  )
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this `=>`

This was not supported back in dart version < 2.2